# Applying Regex.Match() with String.Join()

Tags: c#, regex, odata

I am working on implementing a .net core OData interface.

One field: FileStore is of type IEnumerable. In order to get this field in excel, I converted it to string using string.join. Now, I want to apply a regex on it to get values only matching "MKOIP-P0".

```
return Ok(_assetDiscoveryService.GetAllAssets(tenantGuid).Select(a => new ODataAsset
        { 
        FileStore = a.Type == "VMWare.Compute/virtualMachines" ? string.Join(",", a.VSphereSpecificInfo.DiskInfo.Select(b => b.Filestore) ): null,

        }).AsQueryable());
```

I am aware of Regex.Match. but that throws an error: `Cannot implicitly convert source type "System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match" to target type "String".`

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: could you share the code that has the Regex.Match? Do you want to check if b.FileStore contains "MKOIP-P0"?

Comment: `return Ok(_assetDiscoveryService.GetAllAssets(tenantGuid).Select(a => new ODataAsset
            {
                FileStore = a.Type == "VMWare.Compute/virtualMachines"
                    ? Regex.Match(string.Join(",", a.VSphereSpecificInfo.DiskInfo.Select(b => b.Filestore)), "*T0*")
                    : null
            }).AsQueryable());`

I wish to display values having MKOIP-P0 only.

Comment: not sure if we need RegEx for this.. see if this works for you:  `FileStore = a.Type == "VMWare.Compute/virtualMachines" ? string.Join(",", a.VSphereSpecificInfo.DiskInfo.Where(b => b.FileStore.Contains("MKOIP-P0")).Select(b => b.Filestore) ): null,`

Comment: `FileStore = a.Type == "VMWare.Compute/virtualMachines" ? string.Join(",", a.VSphereSpecificInfo.DiskInfo.Select(b => b.Filestore.Contains("MKOIP-P0").ToString())) : null`
Modified it a little and it worked. But, instead of the real value, it is returning True False values.

Comment: the code you have now will return True or False,, as .Contains returns boolean values. What was the error that you were getting with my code? The code that I shared first filters (Where) the ones that matches MKOIP-P0, and .Select returns them.

Comment: the error I was getting was - DiskInfo does not contain the definition for FileStore.

Comment: Try this: `FileStore = a.Type == "VMWare.Compute/virtualMachines" ? string.Join(",", a.VSphereSpecificInfo.DiskInfo.Select(b => b.Filestore).Where(fs => fs.Contains("MKOIP-P0")) ): null,`

Comment: This worked. Thank you so much Matt :)

Comment: @Matt.G Please post your solution as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the requirement is to check if b.FileStore contains a constant string "MKOIP-P0", we could just use string.Contains method:

```
FileStore = a.Type == "VMWare.Compute/virtualMachines" ? string.Join(",", a.VSphereSpecificInfo.DiskInfo.Select(b => b.Filestore).Where(fs => fs.Contains("MKOIP-P0")) ): null,
```